# How can we represent the following case in limit notation?

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose, we have the following sequence:

$$ 1, 2, 3,..., n $$

This sequence doesn't converge as it extends to $ \infty $.

**How can we represent this case using limit notation?**

Is the following correct?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\infty$$

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: A sequence is typically defined as a function from $\Bbb{N}_0$ to $\Bbb{R}$ and its notation is typically $a_n$. So in your case, you want to say $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$, where $a_n=n$. That's correct, but the other way is more used.

Comment: @manooooh I think you should post that as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, combining the meanings of $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ and $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\infty$ discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_involving_infinity).